# Store diffs of binary files to Git with rdiff-backup or similar tool

Tags: git, rdiff-backup

I read several topic about storing binary files/blobs to Git and got that this is not good idea, and did not found any good approach.

I'd like to make `Git` to create git-objects - diffs of binary files - with a special tool, i.e. `rdiff-backup`.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is : `git` does not store diffs, it stores plain files (see [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for example).

For storage : after a while (or after you call `git gc`), it tries to pack similar files into a packfile ( [see here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) ), where it does somehow use the diff between two files.

I don't know if you can plug into the packfile creation with some external plugin, though.

You would also have to plug into git's similarity detection between files, which heavily relies on spotting similar *lines* (eg : chunks of bytes separated by `'\n'`)